# How do i make a button to generate numbers?

Tags: javascript, dom, button

I'm working an a code that takes a number input from a user and genrates numbers from 0 to whatever number the user provided as input.
I've written the code linking the html and js together, however it still does not perform the function that i want it to do

i created a button element in html and linked it in javscript using the id. each number generated is supposed to have a different background color based on if it is prime, even or odd.
So i have the input element for a number to be entered and a button that is suppose to generate numbers from 0 to whatever number that was entered. for e.g if 5 is entered, the button is to generate numbers 0-5 but the button is not working like that. it only generates the number 0 and stops and im not getting any errors in my console.  Here is the javascript code:

```js
    const button = document.querySelector("button");

    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const num = document.querySelector("#number").textContent;
    const userNum = parseInt(num, 10);
    for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
    let container = document.createElement("div");
    container.textContent = i;
    // function to check if a number is a prime number
    function isPrime(number) {
      if (number <= 1) return false;
      if (number <= 3) return true;

      if (number % 2 === 0 || number % 3 === 0) return false;

      for (let i = 5; i * i <= number; i += 6) {
        if (number % i === 0 || number % (i + 2) === 0) return false;
      }

      return true;
    }

    if (isPrime(i)) {
      container.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else if (i % 2 === 0) {
      container.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else if (i % 2 !== 0) {
      container.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
    let containerElement = document.querySelector("#numberContainer");
    containerElement.appendChild(container);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

its because your using

```
const num = document.querySelector("#number").textContent;
```

The textContent property returns the text content of the element, the #number element is an input field, it doesn't have any text content to return.

So num ends up with a value of undefined.

Instead, to get the value entered by the user into the #number input field, you need to use the .value property:

```
const num = document.querySelector("#number").value;
```

also when generating the divs, you need to convert i to a string to set the textContent, otherwise it will coerce to a string and only show "0":

```
container.textContent = i.toString();
```

here is the full code

```
const button = document.querySelector("button"); 

button.addEventListener("click", () => {

  // Get user input correctly
  const userNum = document.querySelector("#number").value;
  
  for (let i = 0; i <= userNum; i++) {

    let container = document.createElement("div");

    // Convert i to string for textContent 
    container.textContent = i.toString(); 

    // Check if prime
    function isPrime(number) {
      // prime check logic
    }
    
    if (isPrime(i)) {
      container.style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
    } else if (i % 2 === 0) {
       container.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
       container.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }

    let containerElement = document.querySelector("#numberContainer");
    containerElement.appendChild(container);

  }

});
```